# How do I navigate VS Code debugger variables without the mouse?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I want to drill down into the variables shown during debugging in VS Code using the arrow keys or indeed anything but the mouse.

I read the [debugging docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging).

Comment: Please [edit] to add details, so the info's all together

Comment: Bare in mind, you can use a multitude of different debuggers with VS Code and each one would come with its own syntax. If you have a C-based project, for example, you can use LLDB in VS Code and there is a copious amount of documentation using LLDB (with just the keyboard). I'm not familiar with VS Code's default debugger so I would start there. If its a proprietary debugger then documentation will be limited.

Comment: what info did i leave out and where do you want it @wjandrea

Comment: @Jack Oops, sorry for being unclear, I meant your comment. I went ahead and did it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the variables subview, you can use the `Run and Debug: Focus on Variables View` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). If you want to customize that keyboard shortcut, use the `workbench.debug.action.focusVariablesView` command ID.

From there, you can just use standard list navigation (see [How can I navigate and manipulate list views in VS Code using the keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77160922/11107541)). Quoting the partial summary portion of the answer there:

> Up and down arrow keys go up and down, and left and right arrow keys can be used to expand and collapse nested things. Left inside something nested can be used to jump to the parent of the nest, and <kbd>enter</kbd> can be used to select the focused item, and <kbd>space</kbd> on the parent of a nest can be used to toggle expand/collapse of it. Hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and use arrow keys to scroll