# Is there a keyboard shortcut for scrolling down in the VS Code quick fix menu?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

There is a keyboard shortcut for scrolling down and up in the intellisense suggestion menu. I forget what the default binding is but I use "j". However, this doesn't apply to the quick fix menu. I couldn't find any mention of a keyboard shortcut for this behavior. Would I have to write my own extension?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77160922/11107541 probably. seems so according to Mark's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you should use the `list` scroll commands:

1. `list.scrollDown` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>DownArrow</kbd>
2. `list.scrollUp` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>UpArrow</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `selectPrevCodeAction` and `selectNextCodeAction` is what we need.

Sadly I was not able to make `j / k` work for whatever reason, but `ctrl+j / ctrl+k` worked just fine.

Here are the settings you want:

```json
    {
        "key": "ctrl+j",
        "command": "selectPrevCodeAction",
        "when": "codeActionMenuVisible"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+k",
        "command": "selectNextCodeAction",
        "when": "codeActionMenuVisible"
    }
```

Comment: depends on interpretation of the word "scroll". this moves selection. typically, when people say "scroll" though, they don't want to move selection. anyhow, if you're convinced you have the right interpretation of the question, you should have flagged to close as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/68685670/11107541. see [answer].